# Core Data Migration: 'Can't merge models with two different entities...'

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I added new version to Core Data model. I added new attribute to one entity (`Seriese`)

But it raise exception

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Seriese''
```

I use the following code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationPrivateDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CoreDataTutorialPart4.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,  
                                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Any suggestions to solve this error?  I don't want to lose the saved data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue more than likely comes from how you load you managed object model. The default way is to merge the models in the bundle, however in this case you actually have two models with the same entities (v1 and v2)... it is explained nicely here....[Migration Issues](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/core-data-migration-problems.html)

Comment: I read the link but the momd not be found in my bundle , could u give me more details

Comment: In Xcode did you choose "Design->Data Model->Add Model Version" from the toolbar or did you just edit the existing model?

Comment: I did Design->Data Model->Add Model Version

Comment: Sometimes Xcode can get in a bit of a bind. First thing to do is to do a Clean All, then manually delete the Build directory, delete the app from the device / simulator and restart xcode. Then try again, it that doesn't work you may need to remove the model altogether and create a new one. I always start projects (with CoreData) by creating a versioned model (even though I only want 1 version), this ensures the MOMD is set up correctly. Also check the model directory, the folder with the versions in, is added to your target.

Comment: If you still have an issue and want to send me a simple version of the project I can take a look for you.

Comment: how t osend you a sample project

Comment: Zip it up and send to info@locassa.com

Comment: Unfortunately the linked page is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data does not understand that the entity `Seriese` in both models is intended to be the same entity and that it should translate the attributes of the old `Seriese` to the new `Seriese`. Instead, it thinks the new `Seriese` should be treated as an entirely new entity.

This is usually caused by trying to make changes to the new version that automatic migration cannot handle. Automatic migration can handle changes to attribute names, adding an attribute or other changes that don't affect anything beyond a single entity. Once you begin to change relationships and/or add new entities, you have to do a manual migration.

You can call

```
+[NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:destinationModel:error:]
```

... to test if an automatic migration is possible. If it returns nil and/or and error, then you can't.